# Create same session on differen server

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

What is required to create same session on different hosts?
There are two stand alone servers. I do not want to setup a cluster environment. I just want the session created in one server is recognized by other

When I request server A with client C, that(server A) will request to server B (with a flag set in header so that it wont go in loop). When I request server B with client C the session is not recognized on server B. what else do I have to do?
I tried setting jsession id

> I am using apache httpclient to send the request to other server. I
>   have added header and I can see cookie header is same in both server,
>   still its not recognized

```
request.setHeader("cookie", req.getHeader("cookie"));
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

@Aadam  did you tried HttpSession ?

Comment: I am using apache httpclient to send the request to other server. I have added header and I can see cookie header is same in both server, still its not recognised

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions

Comment: I think when  client C sends request to server B with different cookie which not sent from client C to server A .

Comment: so try to use CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); to maintain session between different server with httpclient request.

Comment: I tried its not working, its making 3 sessions in total client a, client b, httpclient